# Avoid a for loop

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, tapply

I am trying to optimize an algorithm and I really want to avoid all my loops. Hence I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the following simple loop:

```
library(FNN)
data <- cbind(1:10, 1:10)

NN.index <- get.knn(data, 5)$nn.index
bc <- matrix(0, nrow(NN.index), max(NN.index))
for(i in 1:nrow(bc)){
  bc[i,NN.index[i,]] <- 1
}
```

were `bc` is a matrix of zeros.

Comment: The code looks good to me. I wouldn't change it.

Answer (score 1):

In R, if the bracket of a matrix `M` take a k-by-2 matrix 'I', then each row of the k-by-2 matrix `I` is recognized as the row and column index of `M`. For example

```
M = matrix(1:20, nrow =4, ncol = 3)
print(M)
I = rbind(c(1,2), c(4,2), c(3,3))
print(M[I])
```

In this case, `M[1,2]`, `M[4,2]` and `M[3,3]` are extracted.
In your case, we can create `row_index` and `col_index` from `NN.index` as below, and then assign `1` to the corresponding entries.

```
bc <- matrix(0, nrow(NN.index), max(NN.index))
row_index <- rep(1:nrow(NN.index), times = ncol(NN.index))
col_index <- as.vector(NN.index)
bc[cbind(row_index, col_index)] <- 1
print(bc)
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, I kind of sorted out, and I believe that the oprimal way of doing this (in terms of computational power) is by defining a sparse matrix. In the sparse matrix you give a vectors of i and a vectos of j that define the non zero entries of the matrix, and you can also define a vector x, that stands for the non zero elements. 

Thanx again!